# Upgrading from Rails 3.0.0 to Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

Long before, I had upgraded my rails project from **2.2.2** to **3.0.0** with the help of a **Rails_uprade** plugin available on github.Now i would like to upgrade my code to Rails 4 and i am looking for a tutorial to guide me.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

[Rails Guilds - A Guide for Upgrading Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)